# How to Run Tests for Installed Django Apps Using Pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest

Using the traditional unit test, I can run tests for an installed Django app using the command: `python manage.py test <name_of_the_installed_app>`

But this is not the case when using pytest as the test runner

How do I run the tests of a third-party app that is included in Django settings installed apps using pytest?

Comment: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @KamalLama I'm aware of running the tests of a Django project and introducing Django settings in pytest.ini. But, I could not find in the docs anything about running tests of third-party apps using pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Afianian, my suggestion for you have two steps:

1. `cd /my/app/dir/`
2. `pytest -c /my/django-project/dir/pytest.ini --rootdir /my/django-project/dir/`

on the `pytest.ini` file you must set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, also you can do this same as below instead of set the `pytest.ini` file:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings" pytest --rootdir /my/django-project
```